# Running script with powershell of Sharepoint Server without connecting to the Sharepoint Server

Tags: 2013, powershell

I have a folder in Sharepoint Server. In the folder, there is a script(.ps1 file), that I can run with powershell.

It works fine with powershell, if I run it when I'm in Sharepoint Server.

But I want to be able to run this script from another computer without connecting to the Sharepoint Server.

How can I make it happen?
Thank you.

The script that I want to run without remote desktop connection:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$vessellist = import-csv -Path "\\server\c$\filepathoftheexcel\myexcel.csv"          
#Get the list used to import the data to            
$l = (Get-Spweb "http://server").GetList("http://server/Lists/mylistname")            
foreach($item in $vessellist)            
{     
    //some process

}
```

**Updated1:**

I ran this commands from my computer :

```
$pass = convertto-securestring "password" -asplaintext -force
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "domain\username",$pass

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName servername –Credential $mycred 
Invoke-Command -Computer servername -credential $mycred -Command{ "C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\addToList.ps1"}

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
$farm


cd..
cd Desktop\folder
.\addToList.ps1
```

I get this error:

> Get-SPWeb : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm
>   is properly configured, currently available, and that you have the
>   appropriate permissions to access the database before trying again.

**Updated2:**

My last command for powershell from my computer is:

```
$pass = convertto-securestring "password" -asplaintext -force
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "domain\username",$pass

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName servername –Credential $mycred 
Invoke-Command -Computer servername -credential $mycred -Command{ "C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\addToList.ps1"}

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
$farm
cd "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
powershell Get-ExecutionPolicy


runas /profile /user:domain\username /savecred  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe  -executionpolicy unrestricted -file C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\addToList.ps1 -ExecutionPolicy ByPass
```

After the last command it doesn't give me any message. It just jump the next new line for the new command:

```
[servername]: PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try Enable-PSRemoting ? It might help

Comment: Yes. It says WinRM already set up to receive requests on this message. WinRM already is set up for remote management on this machine. But in script I get a list of the SP Server with Get-Spweb. So I need to run "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell" command.

Comment: I add my script to question to help you understand.

Comment: @keerthi, Please provide more details for your answer.